# I cant define a new object in javascript and push it into array using inputs without overriding it or causing a error

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, coffeescript

I want to add a post to a new object then push that object into an array of all posts.

When i try to do this i get a duplication error if i dont write post =  new {}
But if i do then i get a TypeError: (intermediate value) is not a function

If anyone can help this would be greatly appreciated.

ps. Additional browny points for anyone who can tell me how to make the array persistant on page reload (/link me a artical)

Javascript:

```
myApp.controller "PostController", ["$scope", ($scope) ->
  $scope.posts = []
  # $scope.post = {}
  $scope.addpost = ->
    $scope.post = new {}
    $scope.post.header = $scope.header
    $scope.pst.content = $scope.content
    $scope.posts.push $scope.post

  return
]
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="PostController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="header" placeholder="Header"></input><p>
    <input type="text" ng-model="content" placeholder="Content"></input><br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addpost()">
      Submit
    </button>
    <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
      <hr>
      <h2>{{post.header}}</h2><br>
      <h4>{{post.content}}</h4><br>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `new {}`, just use the object literal syntax `x = {a: 1, b: 2...}`, which looks like this in Coffeescript:

```
myApp.controller "PostController", ["$scope", ($scope) ->
  $scope.posts = []
  $scope.addpost = ->
    $scope.posts.push
      header: $scope.header
      content: $scope.content
  return
]
```

Comment: Thank you this looks far neater. I appreciate your help.